# How to move Eclipse plugin to different feature using patches?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have required feature `A.feature` and optional feature `B.feature`, latter  has plugin `B.plugin`. I want to move `B.plugin` to under `A.feature`.

Similar question has [been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10785889/whats-a-good-way-to-move-an-eclipse-plug-in-from-one-feature-to-another), but solution requires keeping `B.feature` as dummy feature for people upgrading, because installing new version of it is required for those who had the plugin installed before, however for new users it's unnecessary noise in update site.

So I tried using patches - currently have set up:

1. `B.plugin` - empty, dummy plugin with `id` as before, will be used in patch
2. `B.patch.feature` - includes the dummy `B.plugin`
3. `A.plugin` - copy of old, non-dummy `B.plugin` with new `id`
4. `A.feature` - includes `B.patch.feature`, marked as optional, and `A.plugin`

This seems to work perfectly if `B.feature` was installed before, but if it's not, then during installing the new version of `A.feature` the install process it says

> `B.patch.feature` is not applicable to the current configuration and
>   will not be installed.

and forces user to uncheck `B.patch.feature` before proceeding.

Is there a way to get it to work or is there another approach to take, ultimate goal being having `B.plugin` under `A.feature` in way that `B.feature` will no longer be seen in update site? Having `A.plugin` and non-dummy `B.plugin` active 
 at the same time causes errors.